# ASP.net Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

I've had users consistently getting this error on our homepage:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I can't reproduce this error at all live or on my dev server.  However, in my web.config file I beleive I do have the error code setup correctly:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

All other errors on the site seem to direct to error.aspx just fine, does anyone have any idea why this error would be occurring and how I can catch it?

Comment: You should get the specifics of the error by viewing it on the server as per the message. You can probably figure it put once you see the actual error.

Comment: Have you tried catching the error in the Global.asax file?

Answer (score 3):

You should look in your [Application Log in the Event Viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) to see what the actual error message is. Once you find the error message - you can determine why it is not redirecting.

Another option (*albeit dangerous for public sites*) is to change the error handler to display the actual error message with stack trace so you can troubleshoot the problem (*[customErrors mode='Off'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)*). The users could then deliver the actual error to you instead of the generic error page above.

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```